# Android threads- how to make the thread join, in his run function?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, surfaceview

im making an android application game, using surfaceview and myThread. I have a problem, that I need to use Thread.Join(), in the middle of the frame, it means I will join the thread while his run function is working, and it makes my app stop for some seconds then crash. My question is: How can I stop the thread,in the middle of his run funtion, with the Join() function, or without it. Thanks ! 
Here Im trying to stop the thread.

```
 boolean retry = true;
    int counter = 0;
    while (retry && counter < 1000) {
        try {
            mainThread.setRunning(false);
            mainThread.join();
            retry = false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Thread","Failed to stop thread.");
        }
        counter++;
    }
```

And this is my thread run function:

```
 while(isAlive)
    {
        long start_time=System.nanoTime();
        long wait_time;
        long after_frame_time;
        canvas=surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
        if(canvas!=null)
        {
            gameController.updateAll();
            gameController.drawAll(canvas);
            surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
        after_frame_time=System.nanoTime();
        wait_time=(1000/FPS)-(after_frame_time-start_time)/10000000;
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(wait_time);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And in the onDraw Method, im calling the above code, that stops the thread . ( supossly)

```
public void drawAll(Canvas canvas) {.....
    {
        pauseTheGame();
        isRegulearInitiallized=true;
    }
```

There are a lot of things in addition to this code in the on Draw method, but this thing is happening after the user stop the application, and then come back to it, so it draw once the screen, and then use " PauseTheGame()" , and the problem is that there my thread crashes, and stuck. What should I do ?
Thank you !!!

Comment: Is there an exception thrown, and if so, can you post it?

Comment: already solved ! Thank you ! how can i delete this post ?